# Exercise on Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ as a module over a subalgebra

Tags: modules, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

**Problem**

Let $L= \mathfrak{sl}(3)$ and let $M \subset L$ be the subspace of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}  
    a & b & 0 \\
    c & d & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

with $a, b, c, d \in K$ (field).

1) Prove that $M$ is a Lie subalgebra of L, isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$.

2) Let $L$ be a M-module, by restricting to $M$ the adjoint map $\operatorname{ad}: L \to \mathfrak{gl}(L)$. Write $L$ as a direct sum of irreducible M-modules.

3) Let $h \in \mathfrak{sl}(2)$. For every irreducible M-module of the direct sum, find the highest weight of $h$.

**Attempt to a solution:**

1) To prove that $M$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, I wrote the linear map $f: \mathfrak{sl}(2) \to M$ which associates a generic matrix in $ \mathfrak{sl}(2)$ of the form $\begin{pmatrix}  
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\ 
  \end{pmatrix}$, to the matrix in $M$ of the form $\begin{pmatrix}  
    a & b & 0 \\
    c & d & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Is it correct?

2) It is known that $L$ is semisimple and therefore, by Weyl's Theorem, it is completely reducible, which explains why it is a well-posed question. Now, because $M$ is isomorphic to $ \mathfrak{sl}(2)$, we know that $L$ is a $ \mathfrak{sl}(2)$- module. Therefore, I know that $L = L_0 \bigoplus \oplus_{\alpha \in \Phi/{0}} L_{\alpha}$,  where $L_\alpha= \{x \in L: ad(h)(x) = \alpha(h)x, h \in H \}$ , where $H$ is the maximal toral subalgebra of $L$, $\alpha : H \to K$ is the functional which defines the eigenvalues of the simultaneous basis of eigenvectors of the endormorphisms $ad(h)$ , with $h \in H$. You can prove from there that $H= L_0$.

How can I continue from now on?

(Notation is conforming with James Humphreys, "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representations")

Comment: The sentence "Therefore, I know ..." comes out of the blue. It talks about a certain decomposition of semisimple Lie algebras in terms of Cartan subalgebras, which is not too relevant here, but seems to have nothing to do with the structure theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-modules, which you probably need for this instead.

Comment: I've decomposed $L= H \bigoplus \oplus_{i \neq j} K e_{ij}$, where $e_{ij}$ is the elementary matrix. Then, by calculating brackets $[h, e_{ij}]$, with $h=  \begin{pmatrix}  
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$ , I found the eigenvalues to be 2, 1, 1, 0. Is this correct now?

Comment: What is $H$? Isn't $e_{23}$ an $ad(h)$-eigenvector of eigenvalue $-1$, and $e_{21}$ one of eigenvalue $-2$? -- Btw, in your question 3, is $h$ supposed to be any element of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, or (which makes more sense to me) just the one from your last comment?

Comment: $H$ is the subalgebra of all the diagonal matrices in $\mathfrak{sl(3)}$. Yes, I have those eigenvalues too, I forgot to write them. In question 3 $h$ is supposed to be the one in my last comment (of course just the top left 2x2 block).

Comment: I eventually received the solutions and the eigenspaces turned out to be $V_0 =  \begin{pmatrix}       a & 0 & 0 \\     0 & a & 0 \\      0 & 0 & -2a \\     \end{pmatrix}$ , $V_1=  \begin{pmatrix}       0 & 0 & a \\     0 & 0 & b \\      0 & 0 & 0 \\     \end{pmatrix}$, $V_2=  \begin{pmatrix}       0 & 0 & 0 \\     0 & 0 & 0 \\      a & b & 0 \\     \end{pmatrix}$ and $V_3=  \begin{pmatrix}       a & b & 0 \\     c & -a & 0 \\      0 & 0 & 0 \\     \end{pmatrix}$ . I don't get how they have been computed though: do they come from another choice of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ basis?

Comment: That makes no sense. None of $V_1, V_2, V_3$ is an eigenspace for $ad(h)$ if $h$ is as in your previous comment; for example, $[h, \pmatrix{0&0&a\\0&0&b\\0&0&0}] =\pmatrix{0&0&a\\0&0&-b\\0&0&0}$ which in characteristic $0$ certainly is no scalar multiple of $\pmatrix{0&0&a\\0&0&b\\0&0&0}$.